# New groovydoc syntax (markup) wiki-alike

Tags: groovy, wiki, groovydoc

I saw somewhere in the Groovy family new groovydoc markup (syntax of comments). It was similar to Wiki markup languages, not Javadoc. I had lost url and CAN'T FIND in google :(. Name of this doc formatter was very simply, normal english word. Can anybody remind me?

I will document many groovy business rules scripts, this can be helpful.

Comment: Asciidoc? http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/awesome-asciidoc-include-partial-parts.html

Comment: Yes, thanks. Now I read messages of  Founding Fathers ;)